# How to transform level 2 satellite retrievals to level 3 gridded data

Tags: atmosphere, atmosphere-modelling, remote-sensing, satellites

Usually, I use level-3 gridded satellite data to analyze the spatial and temporal patterns of  atmospheric compositions. However, there were some data sources which only afford level 2 product.

For example, the NH3 total column information derived from [IASI](https://iasi.aeris-data.fr/nh3_iasi_a_arch/) was in level-2 format. But, I saw some paper presented the NH3 distribution very well with those data. An example here.

[image]

A simple template file was uploaded [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Uv6SIDMDDcbVfquZ7vGMoJL_3qQ5yP3V).

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
fc = Dataset("./nh3nn_v2_2_20160209_AM.nc")
print fc.variables['longitude'][:].shape
print fc.variables['latitude'][:].shape
print fc.variables['column'][:].shape
>(633969L,)
>(633969L,)
>(633969L,)
```

For now, I can't find the specific pattern of the orbit. Is there any simple method to transform the original orbit-based data to global gridded data? Any guides or advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: In my experience each satellite has its own strategy to go from Level 2 to Level 3. My recommendation is to contact the providers.